# Is there an analytic expression for the Fresnel pattern from a circular aperture?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, diffraction

I am interested in the Fresnel diffraction pattern (over an entire observation plane, not just the value on-axis) due to a plane wave incident on both **square** and  **circular** apertures.

I have two optics textbooks (*Introduction to Fourier Optics* by Goodman, and *Optics* by Hecht), and both give an analytic expression for the diffraction irradiance pattern from the square aperture in terms of [Fresnel integrals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fresnel_integral), which are tabulated. So far so good.

However, neither book provides the solution (nor even considers it) for the case of a circular aperture.

- Is it really true that the rectangular case is the simpler of the two, and the circular symmetry somehow complicates matters?
- If such an analytic expression exists, could someone point me to it in the literature?

Comment: Why the downvotes here? Is there something wrong with the question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your confusion stems from referring to "Fresnel" diffraction pattern, rather than just looking for the complete equation for the wavefront at any point in space.

Quoting a [randomly-selected paper](https://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/103/5/j35mie.pdf) on high-quality approximations,

the rigorous solution
involves Lommel functions of two variables, which are
defined as series expansions in Bessel functions

To "Fresnel-ify" these analytic functions, you simply :-)  need to decide to what precision and accuracy you want to calculate the wavefront.

Comment: I don't think I'm confused about that - I do not want the solution at any point in space though. Instead I want to take the Fresnel diffraction equation (Eq. 5 here https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/576089/254512), which is an approximation itself, valid above a certain distance, and get a solution for the specific case of a circular aperture. That being said, I think the Lommel functions you mentioned do exactly that. But I believe you don't need to Fresnel-ify them because they already have arisen as a direct solution of the Fresnel diffraction equation.